# How to set the browser version in ruby selenium(WATIR)

Tags: ruby, watir

Since the release of CFT (Chrome For Automation), it's possible to specify the browser version in Selenium. I've come across a Java solution that accomplishes this using ChromeOptions:

java

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setBrowserVersion("116");
```

This code automatically downloads and uses version 116. However, I'm uncertain about how to achieve the same in Ruby Selenium and WATIR. Could you please guide me on how to do this?

Comment: @spickermann We don't need webdrives gem now. Selenium itself provides that feature and that's what I was explaining in the question and I wanted to know how would I do the same in ruby(WATIR).

Comment: @spickermann I'm recommending people who can update to the latest version of Selenium to stop using the webdrivers gem. Selenium can do some cool things that webdrivers cannot — https://github.com/titusfortner/webdrivers/#update-future-of-this-project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see in the [docs](http://watir.com/guides/capabilities/#w3c-capabilities), there is `:browser_version` option

```rb
require "watir"

browser_options = {
  browser_name: "Chrome",
  browser_version: "116",
}

browser = Watir::Browser.new(:chrome, options: browser_options)
```

Comment: You don't even need to specify `browser_name`, it is generated automatically from `:chrome`

Comment: @titusfortner It's automated, I understand that. However, in the provided Java code, users can still opt for an older version, and when they do, it downloads both Chrome and the driver. How can I achieve the same in Ruby Selenium?"

Comment: Yes, this response indeed addressed my question. Thank you. I'm not sure if you're aware, but mentioning the browser version actually triggers the download. Thanks again

Comment: `browser_version` can currently take values of `113`, `114`, `115`, `116`, `117`, `118`, `"stable"`, `"beta"`, `"dev"`, `"canary`"

Comment: If you specify the location of the driver, or have a driver on PATH, Selenium won't manage it for you. You can turn on logging to see what Selenium Manager is doing: `Selenium::WebDriver.logger.level = :debug`

Comment: @titusfortner Indeed, I've just observed it. When I specify the version, it also initiates the automatic download. Previously, I was including the driver path in the `service_options`, which prevented this behavior. Now that I've removed the service_options, I've come to realize that it downloads both the Chrome browser and Chrome driver. It's truly amazing.